# PyMeshLab Saving Exception

Tags: python, mesh, meshlab, pymeshlab

I am trying to perform a very simple operation in `pymeshlab`.

1. Import an stl
2. Count the vertices and facets and print them in a txt file
3. Save the mesh with a different name

I am using this as a test case having isolated the problem in the `ms.save_current_mesh('Output.stl')` part. I am getting an exception with no infromation.

> line 19, in 
> ms.save_current_mesh('Output.stl')
> pymeshlab.pmeshlab.PyMeshLabException

Here is my short script. Please note I have found [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75906225/can-not-save-mesh-when-using-pymeshlabmeshset-save-current-mesh) but there is no answer and I have checked using other methods and the txt file that I have permission to write files into the working directory. To test the following replace `Model.stl` with any stl surface geometry. I have confirmed that the GUI meshlab works perfectly with the stl I am using.
Any Ideas?

```
import pymeshlab
#create a new MeshSet
ms = pymeshlab.MeshSet()

#load a new mesh

ms.load_new_mesh('Model.stl')
print(ms.current_mesh().vertex_number(),'vertex')
print(ms.current_mesh().face_number(), 'faces')

with open("model.txt", "w") as f:
 print("Test file output", file=f)
 print(ms.current_mesh().vertex_number(),'vertex', file=f)
 print(ms.current_mesh().face_number(), 'faces', file=f)
# save the current mesh without face color
ms.save_current_mesh('Output.stl')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem! It appears that pymeshlab uses the working directory path. If the path contains non-latin characters, it throws this generic undescriptive exception.

I changed the working directory to one with only latin characters and it works.